# How can I get the location of switches between these 2 sorted linked lists

Tags: c++

I've been struggling with this homework for so long that I really appreciate any help I can get.

The problem I am stuck on is pretty simple but a bit confusing.

So the big part of the problem is solved (As mentioned in the first code comment — to find the maximum sum path between these two sorted linked lists)

```c
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ADSL Assignment 1 | Maximum Sum Problem.                                |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| * You are provided with two sorted lists as input.
| * Those lists have some nodes in common.
| * Find a new list composed of the union of the nodes of those two lists.
| * To create the new list, you should take parts (paths of one or more nodes) from each list and merge them together.
| * You are allowed to switch between the two original lists only at intersections (same node in both lists).
| * in order to figure out the resulting list having the path that represents the greatest maximum total.
| Input:
|   * Two Sorted Linked Lists.
| Output:
|   * New list containing maximum sum path.
|   * Location of switches between the 2 lists.
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    int num;
    Node* next;
    Node(int data, Node* next = 0) {    this->num = data;  this->next = next;     }
    Node() {    this->next = 0;     }
};
class List {
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    List() {    head = tail = 0;    }

    void AddToTail(int data) {
        if (head == 0) head = tail = new Node(data);
        else {
            tail->next = new Node(data);
            tail = tail->next;
            tail->next = 0;
        }
    }

    void Print() {
        Node* temp = head;
        if (temp == 0) cout << "Empty List\n";
        while(temp != 0) {
            cout << temp->num << "\t";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

};

List MaxSumPath(Node* head1, Node* head2)
{
    List    l;

    Node*   temp1   = 0;
    Node*   temp2   = 0;
    Node*   temp    = 0;
    Node*   result  = 0;
    int     sum1    = 0;
    int     sum2    = 0;

    while (head1 || head2) {

        temp1 = head1;
        temp2 = head2;
        sum1 = sum2 = 0;

        while (head1 && head2)
        {
            if (head1->num < head2->num)
            {
                sum1 += head1->num;
                head1 = head1->next;
            }
            else if (head2->num < head1->num)
            {
                sum2 += head2->num;
                head2 = head2->next;
            }
            else break;
        }


        if (head1 == 0)
        {
            while (head2){
                sum2 += head2->num;
                head2 = head2->next;
            }
        }

        if (head2 == 0)
        {
            while (head1){
                sum1 += head1->num;
                head1 = head1->next;
            }
        }

        if (sum1 >= sum2)
        {

            if (result == 0) {
                result = temp1;
                temp = head1;
            }
            else {
                temp->next = temp1;
                temp = head1;
            }
        }

        else if (sum1 < sum2) {

            if(result == 0) {
                result = temp2;
                temp = head2;
            }
            else {
                temp->next = temp2;
                temp = head2;
            }
        }

        if (head1 && head2 && temp) {
            head1 = head1->next;
            head2 = head2->next;
            temp->next = 0;
        }
    }

    while (result)
    {
        l.AddToTail(result->num);
        result = result->next;
    }
    return l;
}


int main() {

    List l1;
    l1.AddToTail(1);
    l1.AddToTail(3);
    l1.AddToTail(30);
    l1.AddToTail(90);
    l1.AddToTail(120);
    l1.AddToTail(240);
    l1.AddToTail(511);

    List l2;
    l2.AddToTail(0);
    l2.AddToTail(3);
    l2.AddToTail(12);
    l2.AddToTail(32);
    l2.AddToTail(90);
    l2.AddToTail(125);
    l2.AddToTail(240);
    l2.AddToTail(249);


    cout << "List 1 = ";
    l1.Print();
    cout << "List 2 = ";
    l2.Print();

    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "List 3 = ";

    List result = MaxSumPath(l1.head, l2.head);
    result.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

What I can't get my hands on is the switches between two these linked lists, in the example given they should be 3 & 240

A switch is a number that the path continue from in order to get to the maximum sum path, and it only can be a common node between the two lists.

The original problem on [geeksforgeeks](http://geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-linked-list-two-sorted-linked-lists-common-nodes/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sliding window where the sliding window runs from point of first intersection to second. For two linked lists, there exist two sliding windows. The sliding window with larger sum of the two has to be in the new linked list.
You can have two temp variables pointing to the first element in each linked list after the sliding window's first intersection. And you can point the intersection node to that address once you figure out the path.